# facet_wrap Title rename

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change titles of predictions using `facet_wrap` but I can't the code I am using is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

models <- list(fit_slope, fit_vel)  # List of models
# Create an empty list to store plot objects
plot_list <- list()

# Loop through each model
for (i in seq_along(models)) {
  model <- models[[i]]
  effect_name <- c("ksn", "velo")[i]  # Effect name for facet label
  
  # Calculate conditional effects
  pooled_effect <- conditional_effects(model, effects = effect_name, sd = TRUE,
                                       LBLs = c("ksn", "velo"))
  
  # Plot the effect
  plot_obj <- plot(pooled_effect, points = TRUE, plot = FALSE)[[1]] +
    
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(~., ncol = 1, scales = "free_y",
               labeller = labeller(.cols = c(ksn = "ksn", velo = "Velo")))
  
  # Add plot object to the list
  plot_list[[i]] <- plot_obj
}

# Arrange plots in a grid of subplots
grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, ncol = 2)
```

It would be great if someone help me out in this regard

I am getting this output

[image]

Comment: Hi Sajid! Welcome to StackOverflow. If you could make your example reproducible (i.e. make it so another person can recreate the models) that would be great!

Comment: if the plot is just a regular ggplot object, then the ways of titling the plots are the same as those other answers